# Sonicwall Fake network

Tags: subnet, sonicwall

I have a Sonicwall NSA 3500.  My LAN is 192.168.0.0/16 with my Sonicwall at 192.168.11.251

I have a new device that I need to connect, it has 2 NIC cards one communicates with the network, the other via wireless infrastructure with Wireless Data recorders.  However that secondary interface is also setup for 192.168.0.0/16.

So my question is, is this setup even possible?  I need to be able for computers in my primary LAN to be able to talk to the server on this secondary network.

I really need some help setting this one up?

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change one network or the other.  The new device won't know which interface any particular traffic belongs to.

Comment: I'll add that the Sonicwall can do NAT to translate the other network to something different (sometimes done when two networks between a VPN share the same address space), but the translation needs to happen both ways (meaning the "new device" needs to be able to NAT as well).